# Spacy Pipeline?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

So lately I've been playing around with a WikiDump.
I preprocessed it and trained it on Word2Vec + Gensim

Does anyone know if there is only one script within Spacy that would generate
tokenization, sentence recognition, part of speech tagging, lemmatization, dependency parsing, and named entity recognition all at once

I have not been able to find clear documentation
Thank you

Answer (score 13):

Spacy gives you all of that with just using `en_nlp = spacy.load('en'); doc=en_nlp(sentence)`. The [documentation](https://spacy.io/docs/#getting-started) gives you details about how to access each of the elements.

An example is given below:

```
In [1]: import spacy
   ...: en_nlp = spacy.load('en')

In [2]: en_doc = en_nlp(u'Hello, world. Here are two sentences.')
```

Sentences can be obtained by using `doc.sents`:

```
In [4]: list(en_doc.sents)
Out[4]: [Hello, world., Here are two sentences.]
```

Noun chunks are given by `doc.noun_chunks`:

```
In [6]: list(en_doc.noun_chunks)
Out[6]: [two sentences]
```

[Named entity](https://spacy.io/docs/#examples-entities) is given by `doc.ents`:

```
In [11]: [(ent, ent.label_) for ent in en_doc.ents]
Out[11]: [(two, u'CARDINAL')]
```

Tokenization: You can iterate over the doc to get tokens. `token.orth_` gives str of the token.

```
In [12]: [tok.orth_ for tok in en_doc]
Out[12]: [u'Hello', u',', u'world', u'.', u'Here', u'are', u'two', u'sentences', u'.']
```

POS is given by `token.tag_`:

```
In [13]: [tok.tag_ for tok in en_doc]
Out[13]: [u'UH', u',', u'NN', u'.', u'RB', u'VBP', u'CD', u'NNS', u'.']
```

Lemmatization:

```
In [15]: [tok.lemma_ for tok in en_doc]
Out[15]: [u'hello', u',', u'world', u'.', u'here', u'be', u'two', u'sentence', u'.']
```

Dependency parsing. You can traverse the parse tree by using `token.dep_` `token.rights` or `token.lefts`. You can write a function to print dependencies:

```
In [19]: for token in en_doc:
    ...:     print(token.orth_, token.dep_, token.head.orth_, [t.orth_ for t in token.lefts], [t.orth_ for t in token.rights])
    ...:     
(u'Hello', u'ROOT', u'Hello', [], [u',', u'world', u'.'])
(u',', u'punct', u'Hello', [], [])
(u'world', u'npadvmod', u'Hello', [], [])
...
```

For more details please consult the spacy documentation.

Answer (score 0):

They've updated the spacy version to spacy-alpha V2.0.0.

You can check it here for the new documentation [Here](http://alpha.spacy.io/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Github issue thread for adding models to the pipeline for new languages, or improving current ones:

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3056

From my understanding, it sounds like in the worst case scenario you might need to label data in the format that spacy requires using your own models; then use this labelled data to train models in spacy.